# Video call with peerjs socket.io nodeJS only works sometimes

Tags: node.js, peerjs, videocall

I need help to set a simple video call web aplication inside a php platform. But i have several problems. I followed several tutorials to achieve that, but still i cant do it.

What i need to achieve? I need to set several video calls (even simultaneously) just for 2 cameras (users) each one, in separate "rooms" set by php pages of wordpress.

Examples:

In "www.mywebsite.com/interviews/my_specific_name_room/" only 2 users in a video call.
In "www.mywebsite.com/visits/my_other_specific_name_room/" only 2 users in a video call.
Etc.
What i already have done? I have a VPS with apache php mysql and nodejs. The video call works under https protocol. The tutorials i followed let me set "https://www.mywebsite.com:3030/" and to make video call.

But What are my problems? The problem is that sometimes the video call works and sometime dont. I dont know why. When i access "https://www.mywebsite.com:3030/" from my laptop and from my cell phone, the video call works almost always between those devices. Even when a friend in my same city access "https://www.mywebsite.com:3030/" and i do the same, the video call works fine. But with other friends in the city, and with every friend in other places of my country the video call never works. We just see our own video. Really i dont know why. I´ve tried some solutions but i dont know much of nodeJS.

My code from the server:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(3030, function () {
    console.log("Servidor iniciado en el puerto 3030");
});

const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
    debug: true
});

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/www/index.html');
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    serveClient: false,
    // below are engine.IO options
    origins: '*:*',
    transports: ['polling'],
    pingInterval: 10000,
    pingTimeout: 5000,
    cookie: false
});
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('the-interview', (data) => {
        socket.join(data.room);
        socket.to(data.room).broadcast.emit('user-connected', data.id)
        console.log(data.id)
    })
})
```

My code from www/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interviews Mywebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/5.6.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
    <style>
        #videogrid {
            width: 100%;
            display: grid;
        }

        #videowrap {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        #losvideos {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 56.25%;
            max-width: 900px;
        }

        video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #conttu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        #contyo {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .watermark {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 40px;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0.3;
            transform: scale3d(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
        }

        .menu {
            position: absolute;
            height: 120px;
            bottom: -120px;
            transition: all 0.7s ease;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            width: 60%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -30%;
            border-radius: 70px 70px 0 0;
            z-index: 1;
            display: grid;
            align-items: center;
            grid-auto-flow: column;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 30px;
        }

        #losvideos:hover .menu {
            bottom: 0px;
            transition: all 0.7s ease;
        }

        .menu .icono {
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #5d59b5;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .menu .icono:hover {
            background-color: #383485;
        }

        .menu .icono:active {
            background-color: #24206d;
        }

        .menu .icono i {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .menu #nofull {
            display: none;
        }

        .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 120px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #900;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 110%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -65px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
        }

        .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Interviews Mywebsite</h2>

    <div id="videogrid">
        <div id="videowrap">
            <div id="losvideos">
                <div class="watermark">
                    <img src="logo.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div id="conttu">
                    <video id="video_other" autoplay></video>
                </div>
                <div id="contyo">
                    <video id="my_video" autoplay muted></video>
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div id="full" class="icono tooltip">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-fullscreen"></i>
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Pantalla completa</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="silencio" class="icono tooltip">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-microphone-off"></i>
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Silenciar micrófono</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="stopVideo" class="icono tooltip">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-video-off"></i>
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Apagar mi cámara</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let miStream;

    const socket = io()

    var my_video = document.querySelector("#my_video");
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                console.log('Showing my own video')
                my_video.srcObject = stream;
                miStream = stream;
                peer.on('call', call => {
                    call.answer(stream)
                    const video_other = document.getElementById('video_other');
                    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
                        console.log('Showing other user's video 1')
                        video_other.srcObject = userVideoStream;
                    })
                })
                socket.on('user-connected', userID => {
                    connectToNewUser(userID, stream)
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            });
    }

    var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
        path: '/peerjs',
        host: '/',
        port: '3030'
    });     

    var room = '12345'; //room name, set by php

    // Send interviews data to server
    peer.on('open', id => {
        socket.emit('the-interview', {
            room: room,
            id: id
        });
    })

    // Function for send our ID and video to the other user
    const connectToNewUser = (userID, stream) => {
        const call = peer.call(userID, stream);
        const video_other = document.getElementById('video_other');
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
            console.log('Showing other user's video 2')
            video_other.srcObject = userVideoStream;
        })
    }


    // other "work in progress" stuff for video call UI 

    // funcion para el silencio
    function silencio() {
        const enabled = miStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
        if (enabled) {
            miStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
            $('#silencio i').removeClass('mdi-microphone-off').addClass('mdi-microphone');
        } else {
            $('#silencio i').removeClass('mdi-microphone').addClass('mdi-microphone-off');
            miStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
        }
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#silencio', function () {
        silencio();
    });

    // funcion para apagar cámara
    function stopVideo() {
        const enabled = miStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
        if (enabled) {
            miStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
            $('#stopVideo i').removeClass('mdi-video-off').addClass('mdi-video');
        } else {
            $('#stopVideo i').removeClass('mdi-video').addClass('mdi-video-off');
            miStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#stopVideo', function () {
        stopVideo();
    });

    // Pantalla completa
    $(document).on('click', '#full', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('activado')) {
            exitFullScreen();
        } else {
            toggleFullScreen();
        }
    })

    function toggleFullScreen() {
        var losvideos = document.getElementById("losvideos");
        if (losvideos.requestFullscreen)
            if (document.fullScreenElement) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else {
                losvideos.requestFullscreen();
            }
        else if (losvideos.msRequestFullscreen)
            if (document.msFullscreenElement) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            } else {
                losvideos.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        else if (losvideos.mozRequestFullScreen)
            if (document.mozFullScreenElement) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else {
                losvideos.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
        else if (losvideos.webkitRequestFullscreen)
            if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            } else {
                losvideos.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
        else {
            alert("Fullscreen API is not supported");
        }
    }

    $('#losvideos').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function (e) {
        var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
        var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

        $('#full i').removeClass('mdi-fullscreen-exit').addClass('mdi-fullscreen');
        $('#full').removeClass('activado');

        if (event == "FullscreenOn") {
            $('#full i').removeClass('mdi-fullscreen').addClass('mdi-fullscreen-exit');
            $('#full').addClass('activado');
        }
    });

    function exitFullScreen() {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#contyo', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('big')) {
            $('#contyo').removeClass('big').attr('style', false)
            $('#conttu').attr('style', false)
        } else {
            $('#conttu').css({ 'width': '250px', 'z-index': '1', 'right': '10px', 'bottom': '10px', 'top': 'unset', 'left': 'unset' })
            $('#contyo').css({ 'width': '100%', 'z-index': '0', 'right': '0', 'bottom': '-4px' }).addClass('big')
        }
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to implement TURN and STUN stuff in this code.

Please, i really need help. I always search everywhere before make a question. For me, it is already a great success to have managed to program something to make video calls without using third-party services.

But my priority now is to make that video calls always work fine, no matter the browser, location... nothing. If somebody can offer a suggestion to achieve my other goal, the "rooms" thing, i will appreciate so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how large your project is. However with my small project this solution work very well.
All you need is register an account in https://xirsys.com/ and register for a free TURN server service. After that, in the client side code, in the Peer initation, you add the config of the peer constructor in the iceserver.

```
var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    path: '/peerjs',
    host: '/',
    port: '3030',
    config: {'iceServers':.......}
});
```

I hope that my answer will help you.